# Laravel mail::table not rendering a table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I had a problem on my mail::table in Laravel Markdown Mailables. The table is not rendering. I have also no indents on it.

emails/inquiry.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
#New Inquiry

We have received a new inquiry

@component('mail::table')
| Laravel       | Table         | Example  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| --------:|
| Col 2 is      | Centered      | $10      |
| Col 3 is      | Right-Aligned | $20      |
@endcomponent

Thanks
@endcomponent
```

Mailtrap output

[image]

Comment: It is rendering a table. Markdown one

Comment: what do you mean markdown one?

Comment: You are rendering html, which in all cases ignores newline characters. You need to add the <br> tag yourself to start a new row

Comment: Well, I do not understand why do I need to add br. In my other project with markdown, it would render

Comment: My concern is on the table. Not rendering just copy it from the docs